# ruby-on-rails check if query result is empty (Model.find)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i´m using ruby on rails and trying to check if a query is returning a value or not.

This is the query:

```
@search = Customer.find_by_name($login_name)
```

If the query finds a result, everything is fine, but how can i react on empty results?

I tried:

```
if @search.empty?
  flash[:notice] = 'Username nicht bekannt'
  redirect_to :action => :login
end
```

But i get an error:

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

Any Ideas what went wrong?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use this to check for nil as well as empty cases:

```
@search.blank?
```

For the opposite case (NOT nil and NOT empty), use [.present?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F):

```
@search.present? #equivalent of !@search.blank?
```

The reason your query returned `nil`  instead of `empty` is :

```
Customer.find_by_name($login_name)
```

always returns one result of object `Customer` or `nil` if there is no such result,

while something like:

```
Customer.where(:name=>$login_name)
```

will return you `ActiveRecord::Relation` (which can have 0-n results) always. and `empty?`  method will work on it

Answer (score 2):

If no result is found, `find_by_name` returns a nil object, rather than an empty array. To check whether a customer was found, you can use `if @search.nil?` or simply `if !@search` or `unless @search`, since nil is falsy in ruby.

```
@search = Customer.find_by_name($login_name)
unless @search
  flash[:notice] = 'Username nicht bekannt'
  redirect_to :action => :login
end
```